# How to include 2 bibliographies with natbib and TeXlipse

Tags: natbib, texlipse

I am using TeXlipse on Windows 7. I am writing my PhD Thesis memo, and want to have 2  list of references on the same document, as follows:

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

....

\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\usepackage{bibunits}

....

\begin{document}

...

\include{chap1/chap1} %Chapter 1

\include{chap2/chap2} %Chapter 2, etc.

......

\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{bib/main.bib}

\begin{bibunit}[chicago]

\def\bibname{Author's Publications}

\nocite{*} \putbib[bib/MyOwnPublications]

\end{bibunit}

\end{document}

In this example:
- **main.bib** which includes the full list of entries properly referenced along the text  (with \cite{} commands), and processed using bibtex.

- **MyOwnPublications.bib**, listing sequentially ALL my publications (with \nocite*) on a special chapter entitled "Author's Publications", placed right before the full reference listing.

But the thing is that TeXlipse does not seem to process MyOwnPublications.bib

Any help on this?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over terminology: A bibliography created by bibtex or biblatex/biber does *not* reside in a `.bib` file. Are you talking about creating two different bibliographies in one and the same document? If so, please edit your posting to clarify your objective.

Comment: Done! Hope it is more clear now...

Comment: So, you've created two separate bib files, and the contents of the two bib files need to be displayed in separate parts of the document?

Comment: That's correct. The first bib file (main.bib) will appear at the end of the document, with the references made along the text. The second bib file (MyOwnPublications.bib) will appear in another part of the document, just listing (\nocite*) all its content.

Comment: You really need to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) showing what you've done so far. In particular, you need to show which extra packages (`chapterbib`, `multibib`, etc) you're trying to employ. Finally, since you mention that TeXlipse may have some issues, is there a possibility for you to use a different frontend program?

Comment: Or just do the compilation at the command line? (I'm assuming even Windows has a command line somewhere?)